# How can I create a dataframe "window" or slice to manipulate?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a rather large dataframe that I need to access by pieces, which are determined by a function.
Like this

```
df
             gtin                          serial  box_number  item_nr_in_box
0   7804320303178  0107804********************119           0                0
1   7804320303178  0107804*********************19           0                0
2   7804320303178  0107804*********************29           0                0
3   7804320303178  0107804*********************39           0                0
4   7804320303178  0107804*********************49           0                0
5   7804320303178  0107804*********************99           0                0
6   7804320303178  0107804*********************89           0                0
```

piece of dataframe determined by dynamic values like:

```
df[df['gtin']==my_gtin][start:end]
```

In these places I need to change some column values like box_number and item_nr_in_box, for example:

```
df[df['gtin']==my_gtin][start:end].assign(box_number=1,item_nr_in_box=range(start,end))
```

This works and shows on screen a new dataframe.

I want to apply the new values to existing df, but I can't seem to be able to do anything with the result. Neither set the values in the original dataframe with new ones or even to append the result  of assign() to an empty dataframe.

I get either complains with "Cannot index with multidimensional key", or gives me a CopyWarning when trying different ways of doing it with .loc or without.

Btw, the `df[df['gtin']==my_gtin][start:end].assign(box_number=1,item_nr_in_box=range(start,end)).index` gives: `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')` . So I don't even understand where multidimensionality comes in.

I want something like

```
df_link=df.loc[ df['gtin']==mygtin][start:end] ]
df[df_link]=df[df_link].assign( ... )
```

But I get, "Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only"

What's the correct way to do that, preferrably without creating a duplicate df?

(Pandas 0.24.2, Ubuntu 18.04.LTS)

Update:

An example df construction:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'gtin': ['ABC']*10 + ['DEF']*5, 'serial': range(start,start+15), 'box_number': [0]*15, 'item_nr_in_box':[0]*15 })
```

Comment: Can you provide code to load the input data into a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chained indexing` is not recommended as can be seen in the docs. You could create a new column `gtin_num` as your `row number` within each `gtin` value and then use `.loc` like this:

```
start = 0
end = 3
df['gtin_num'] = df.groupby(['gtin']).cumcount()
df.loc[(df['gtin']=='ABC') & (df['gtin_num'].isin(range(start, end))), ['box_number', 'item_nr_in_box']] = 1, range(start, end)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked, and I am accepting it. I am still stumped as to how this is much different from what I tried to do. All I wanted is to dynamically set a range of rows to update columns at.

Comment: You are welcome. The problem is with chain indexing because each indexing step can return a view or a copy and there is where things get tricky, search for chain indexing pandas if you want to know more.